# Setup Intent with Google Pay shows 0$

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, google-pay

I am using Stripe's Setup Intents to collect payment information before actually charging the customer on a later date (after their information was confirmed). For this i was also testing Google Pay. And while it worked fine for charging the customer the UI was a bit misleading/confusing.
The pop-up where the customer needs to confirm their intent to pay with Google Pay shows a price of 0$, which obviously is not correct. We already have a projected amount we will charge the customer and thus we would also like to display that there (or at least show no value). Is this only because of being in testing environment? And if not, is there a way to customize this?

For what it is worth here is the code we using (`clientSecret` is the secret returned by the SetupIntent creation):

```
  const options = {
    clientSecret,
    // Fully customizable with appearance API.
    appearance: {},
    loader: 'always'
  }
  elements = stripe.elements(options)

  ({ error } = await stripe.confirmSetup({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: window.location.href + '/purchase/' + props.purchase.uuid + '/confirmation'
    }
  }))
```

[image: Google Pay with Stripe's Setup Intent]

Answer (score 0):

That's just how it works in Google Pay's UI when you're accepting the card without a payment(so in this case, using a SetupIntent to save it). You can't do anything about it since it's part of Google's own sheet.

Comment: Okay thanks. I am just wondering if this has any legal implications. Obviously we make it clear on our side what amount will be charged in the future and the button to Google Pay also is called "Confirm Purchase", but that last confirm on Googles side seems a bit unclear to me (at least considering German law)

Answer (score 0):

I raised this issue on the flutter-stripe github repo and they said they would resolve using these steps, they might help:

> Amount is displayed incorrectly as argument in our API. It should be
> part of createplatformpaypayment method. Google pay should get the
> amount displayed on the setupintent in stripe.

https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/1250

Comment: Thanks, but i think your linked issue is specific to the flutter client of stripe. I probably should have tagged this as javascript.